# Basel's problem: $5\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\phi^k-1\over \phi^{2k}}\cdot{1\over k^2}=\zeta(2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, zeta-functions, golden-ratio

Golden ratio:$\phi$
$$5\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\phi^k-1\over \phi^{2k}}\cdot{1\over k^2}=\zeta(2)\tag1$$

We'll known Basel's problem

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{1\over k^2}=\zeta(2)\tag2$$

How do I transform $(1)$ to $(2)?$

Extra information:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\phi^k-1\over \phi^{2k}}=1\tag3$$

Nothing come to my mind! Any hints?

Comment: I'd say that if $0 < a < b < 1$ then 
$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{b^{k}-a^{k}}{k^{2}}= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{2}}\int_a^b k x^{k-1}dx = \int_a^b \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{ x^{k-1}}{k}dx=\int_a^b \frac{-\ln(1-x)}{x}dx = ...$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to show that

$5\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\phi^k-1\over \phi^{2k}}\cdot{1\over k^2}
=\zeta(2)\tag1
$.

The function you need
is the dilogarithm,
defined by

$L_2(z)
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{z^k}{k^2}
$.

There is much useful info here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence's_function

So you want to show that

$5(L_2(\phi^{-1})-L_2(\phi^{-2}))
=\zeta(2)
$.

Since
$\phi
=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}
$,
$\phi-1
=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}
$,
$1-\phi
=\dfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}
=\dfrac{-1}{\phi}
$
and
$\dfrac{1}{\phi^2}
=\dfrac{(1-\sqrt{5})^2}{4}
=\dfrac{1-2\sqrt{5}+5}{4}
=\dfrac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}
$,
this is equivalent to
$5(L_2(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2})-L_2(\dfrac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}))
=\zeta(2)
$.

According to the Wikipedia page above,
$L_2(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2})
=\dfrac{\pi^2}{10}-\ln^2(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2})
$
and
$L_2(\dfrac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}))
=\dfrac{\pi^2}{15}-\ln^2(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2})
$.

Subtracting these,
the $\ln^2$ terms cancel out
and we get

$\begin{array}\\
L_2(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2})-L_2(\dfrac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}))
&=\dfrac{\pi^2}{10}-\dfrac{\pi^2}{15}\\
&=\dfrac{\pi^2}{30}\\
\text{so}\\
5(L_2(\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2})-L_2(\dfrac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2})))
&=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}\\
&=\zeta(2)\\
\end{array}
$